# Two different controllers using same service and getting same result

Tags: angularjs

I have created two common services for my all master modules. One using ng-resource.

```
app.service('CRUDService',function($resource, $window){
    var data = JSON.parse($window.localStorage["userInfo"]);
    this.crudFunction = function (url) {
        return $resource(url , {id:'@_id'},{
            update: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+data['accessToken']
                }
            },
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+data['accessToken']
                }
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+data['accessToken']
                }
            },
            get :{
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept' : 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+data['accessToken']
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And another service for common functions used by all controllers.

```
app.service('commonService', function (CRUDService) {
    var vm = this;
    var resourceUrl = apiUrl;
    vm.totalItemsTemp = {};
    vm.totalItems = 0;
    vm.currentPage = 1;

    vm.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
        getResultsPage(newPage);
    };  

    vm.load = function(url) {
        resourceUrl = url;
        getResultsPage(1);
    }

    function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {
        CRUDService.crudFunction(resourceUrl).get({"page": pageNumber},function success(response) {
                vm.listdata = response["data"];
                vm.totalItems = response.total;
                vm.currentPage = pageNumber;
            },
            function error(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }

    vm.save = function() {
        CRUDService.crudFunction(resourceUrl).save($.param(vm.newEntry),function(response) {
            if(response["success"] == true)
            {               
                vm.listdata.push(response["inserted_data"]);
                getResultsPage(vm.currentPage);
                $(".modal").modal('hide');
            }
            else
                vm.msg = "Error Saving";

        },function(response) {
            vm.error = response['data'];
        });
    }

    vm.create = function(){
        vm.newEntry = {};
        vm.editData = 0;
        vm.error = {};
    }

    vm.edit = function(id,index) {
        vm.newEntry = angular.copy(vm.listdata[index]);
        vm.editData = 1;
        vm.edit_index = index;
        vm.error = {};
    }

    vm.update = function(id,index) {
        vm.newEntry._method = "PUT";
        CRUDService.crudFunction(resourceUrl).update({id : id} , $.param(vm.newEntry),function(response) {
            if(response["success"] == true)
            {
                vm.listdata[index] = response["updated_data"];
                $(".modal").modal('hide');
                vm.newEntry = {};
            }
            else
                vm.msg = "Error Updating";

        },function(response) {
            vm.error = response['data'];
        });
    }

    vm.remove = function(id, index) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete vm?");
        if (result) {
            CRUDService.crudFunction(resourceUrl).remove({id : id} , $.param({"_method" : "DELETE"}),function(response) {
                getResultsPage(vm.currentPage);
            },function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And I am injecting commonService in my controller like this:

```
app.controller('UserRolesCtrl', function($scope, commonService) {
    commonService.load(apiUrl + 'roles/:id');
    $scope.userroles = commonService;
});

app.controller('SupportMembersCtrl', function($scope, commonService) {
    commonService.load(apiUrl + 'supportmembers/:id');
    $scope.supportmembers = commonService;
});
```

Now I am using tabs for each module. So that my all controllers will be in same page. But all the tabs showing same data. Is it because both controllers are using same variable names? But both the controller's references are different.

Comment: i suggest you  read articles about Services VS Factories in angular js
your implementation is somthing like factories

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because both controllers are using same variable names?

No. Each controller has his own scope so you can create variables with the same name

> But both the controller's references are different.

The service is like *singleton* and you do 2 calls:

- `commonService.load(apiUrl + 'supportmembers/:id');`
- `commonService.load(apiUrl + 'roles/:id');`

**The 1st problem is in method: `run`**

you override `resourceUrl` twice

```
vm.load = function(url) {
    resourceUrl = url;  // <-- here 
    getResultsPage(1);
}
```

**The 2nd problem - you store results under the same variables in service**

```
 vm.listdata = response["data"];
 vm.totalItems = response.total;
 vm.currentPage = pageNumber;
```

The one of solutions is to store data in map under unique key, in your case you can take your URL. Something like:

```
vm.load = function(url) {
    //resourceUrl = url;
    getResultsPage(1, url); // pass url as argument
}

function getResultsPage(pageNumber, url) {
    CRUDService.crudFunction(url).get({"page": pageNumber},function success(response) {
            // ...
        },
        function error(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am storing results under same variable names. But while initialization of controller,  I am storing those variable values to that particular controller's scope.  So they should not get conflict.

Comment: @AnsuyaSindha You have one service for both controllers and each controller tries to store data into the same instance in service.

Comment: It means that on one page i can use that service only for one controller. Can not use for tabbed controllers.

Comment: @AnsuyaSindha not at all. The good way is to use one service for multiple controllers (in your case) but store data in maps and not  as  primitive values. It will give you flexibility and code reuse.

Comment: But in that case, it will not be common for all. @Maxim Shoustin

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs' services are singletons and you are injecting reference to the same service. Try to not assign results into

```
vm.listdata = response["data"];
vm.totalItems = response.total;
vm.currentPage = pageNumber;
```

But return it directly. Both methods saves results under the same properties od singleton. So only last result is available. I think so:)